# Investigating slow query and indexes

Tags: indexing, aws-documentdb

In the logs I found slow queries, but when running them manually it is fast or at least taking indexes into account.
The logs tell me the query part is not using an index, which is available.
Running the query takes the index into account.
Running on AWS DocumentDB (which is MongoDB 3.6 mostly compatible).
The logs tell me this (anonymized field names for the internets ;-) ) :

```
{"op":"update",
"ts":1578041832906,
"ns":"collection",
"command":{
  "q":{"array.field1":{"$binary":"Hzy2Q0TBYEAWadeCtxpXuA==","$type":"3"}},
  "u":{"$set":{"array.$.field2":174}}},
  "nMatched":0,
  "nModified":0,
  "protocol":"op_query",
  "millis":694,
  "planSummary":"IXSCAN",
  "execStats":{
    "stage":"UPDATE",
    "nReturned":"0",
    "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"694.497",
    "inputStages":[{
      "stage":"LIMIT_SKIP",
      "nReturned":"0",
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"694.488",
      "inputStage":{
        "stage":"COLLSCAN",
        "nReturned":"0",
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"694.486"
      }
    },{
     "stage":"IXSCAN",
     "nReturned":"0",
     "executionTimeMillisEstimate":"694.492", 
     "indexName":"_idDocField3",
     "direction":"forward"
    }]
  },
}
```

When running an explain for this on the update

```
collection.explain().update(
    {"array.field1": BinData(3, "Hzy2Q0TBYEAWadeCtxpXuA==")},
    {$set: {"array.$.field2":174}}
)
```

the queryPlanner shows me this

```
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "collection",
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "UPDATE",
      "inputStages": [
        {
          "stage": "LIMIT_SKIP",
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "FETCH",
            "inputStage": {
              "stage": "IXSCAN",
              "indexName": "arrayField1"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "indexName": "_idDocField3",
          "direction": "forward"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "xxxxxxx",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "3.6.0"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

Indexes available are:

- `_id_ { _id:1 }, ops: ~56,000`,
- `_idDocField3 { _id: 1, docField3: 1 }, ops: ~4,200,000`,
- `arrayField1 { "array.field1": 1 }, ops: ~400`,
- `arrayField1DocField3 { "array.field1": 1,  docField3: 1 }, ops: 0`

`array` is an array containing a document and the ids are UUID.
The collection size is about 40,000,000.

And the docs are a bit contradictive:

> https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.6/core/index-multikey/
>   Multikey indexes cannot cover queries over array field(s).
>
> However, starting in 3.6, multikey indexes can cover queries over the non-array fields if the > > index tracks which field or fields cause the index to be multikey. Multikey indexes created in > MongoDB 3.4 or later on storage engines other than MMAPv1 track this data.

Could it be an idea to remove the compound indexes and rely on index intersection?
Or switch the order of the compound indexes?
Anyone who can help me optimizing this?

Comment: Note that DocumentDB is "compatible" with MongoDB, so **any part of MongoDB documentation won't be relevant**. It is expected to be contradictory since they are two entirely different products that happened to look similar.